# Very ample line bundles on a scheme relative to itself

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, line-bundles

I've been working through Hartshorne section II.5, and am currently thinking about very ample line bundles.

It's emphasized that very-ampleness of a line bundle is a relative notion, defined in the context of a morphism of schemes $X\to Y$. It seems to me that, in the category of schemes over $Y$, a particularly basic object to consider is the terminal one, the identity morphism $Y\to Y$. So I was led to wonder: what does it mean for a line bundle on $Y$ to be very ample in this context, and does the condition trivialize somehow?

This seems to involve describing sections of the projection $\mathbb{P}^r_Y\to Y$, but I'm not sure how to do this; I'm having difficulty thinking about projective space over any scheme besides Spec of a field, which isn't a particularly interesting case to consider here.

Comment: Are you asking which line bundles on $Y$ are relatively ample for the identity morphism $Y\to Y$? If so, the answer is ANY line bundle on $Y$.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think relatively ample is the same as very ample.

Comment: Typically, large powers of ample bundles are very ample. You should check what definition you are using.

Comment: The definition I am using is that a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on $X$ is very ample relative to $X\to Y$ if there is an immersion $X\to \mathbb{P}_Y^r$ such that $\mathcal{L}$ is the pullback of the bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}_Y^r$.

Comment: I understand that large powers of ample bundles are very ample, but that doesn't tell me which bundles are very ample.

Comment: Take $r=0$, then $\mathbb{P}^r_Y=Y$. It is trivial to see by definition that for any line bundle $L$ on $Y$, $\mathbb{P}^0_Y=\mathrm{Proj} S_Y(L)$, where $S_Y(L)$ is the symmetric algebra of $L$ and $\mathcal{O}(1)=L$.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the definitions involved to see why this is trivial, so it isn't. Could you expand on it a bit and post it as an answer?